# How to use server with SAML authentication?

Tags: maven, saml

I have server that use saml access
I want to write java application that get dependencies  from this server.
I created settings.xml

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

       <servers>
    <server>
        <id>repoID</id>
        <username>myuser</username>
        <password>mypaswrod</password>
    </server>
  </servers>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>snapshot.build</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>repoID</id>
                    <url>my-url</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>snapshot.build</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>

</settings>
```

when I tried to run mvn clean install I got error from mvn because the SAML.
The error because it the mvn didn't succeed to download the relevant dependencies.
The error from MVN "no checkssum avaliable", when I tried to open the file that was download I got html error of SAML
Does MVN support SMAL access ?